# Changes in QString class between Qt 4.6 and 4.7

Tags: c++, constructor, qt4, overloading

I am now trying to compile [sqlitebrowser](http://sqlitebrowser.sourceforge.net/) with Qt 4.7, during compilation run time I get his error:

```
g++ -c -pipe -O2 -Wall -W -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_QT3SUPPORT_LIB -DQT3_SUPPORT -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_SHARED -I/usr/local/share/qt4/mkspecs/freebsd-g++ -I. -I/usr/local/include/qt4/QtCore -I/usr/local/include/qt4/QtGui -I/usr/local/include/qt4/Qt3Support -I/usr/local/include/qt4 -Isqlite_source -I.moc -I/usr/local/include -o .obj/extendedmainform.o extendedmainform.cpp
In file included from findform.h:24,
                 from form1.h:31,
                 from extendedmainform.h:4,
                 from extendedmainform.cpp:1:
sqlitedb.h: In constructor 'DBBrowserField::DBBrowserField()':
sqlitedb.h:44: error: call of overloaded 'QString(int)' is ambiguous
/usr/local/include/qt4/QtCore/qstring.h:428: note: candidates are: QString::QString(const QByteArray&)
/usr/local/include/qt4/QtCore/qstring.h:426: note:                 QString::QString(const char*)
/usr/local/include/qt4/QtCore/qstring.h:728: note:                 QString::QString(const QString&)
/usr/local/include/qt4/QtCore/qstring.h:106: note:                 QString::QString(QChar)
/usr/local/include/qt4/QtCore/qstring.h:105: note:                 QString::QString(const QChar*)
sqlitedb.h: In constructor 'DBBrowserIndex::DBBrowserIndex()':
sqlitedb.h:58: error: call of overloaded 'QString(int)' is ambiguous
/usr/local/include/qt4/QtCore/qstring.h:428: note: candidates are: QString::QString(const QByteArray&)
/usr/local/include/qt4/QtCore/qstring.h:426: note:                 QString::QString(const char*)
/usr/local/include/qt4/QtCore/qstring.h:728: note:                 QString::QString(const QString&)
/usr/local/include/qt4/QtCore/qstring.h:106: note:                 QString::QString(QChar)
/usr/local/include/qt4/QtCore/qstring.h:105: note:                 QString::QString(const QChar*)
sqlitedb.h: In constructor 'DBBrowserTable::DBBrowserTable()':
sqlitedb.h:73: error: call of overloaded 'QString(int)' is ambiguous
/usr/local/include/qt4/QtCore/qstring.h:428: note: candidates are: QString::QString(const QByteArray&)
/usr/local/include/qt4/QtCore/qstring.h:426: note:                 QString::QString(const char*)
/usr/local/include/qt4/QtCore/qstring.h:728: note:                 QString::QString(const QString&)
/usr/local/include/qt4/QtCore/qstring.h:106: note:                 QString::QString(QChar)
/usr/local/include/qt4/QtCore/qstring.h:105: note:                 QString::QString(const QChar*)
*** Error code 1
```

I checked Qt documentation (both 4.6 and 4.7) to see any change in Qstring constructor, but I see only a new [one overload](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qstring.html#QString-3), so my question what I need to change in sqlitebrowser in order to compile it.

Comment: sqlitedb.h line 44: 'DBBrowserField() : name( 0 ) { }'

Comment: default initialization will do the same thing, so you can just omit the `: name( 0 )`

Answer (score 4):

According to [QString in Qt 4.6](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/qstring.html), there is only [one candidate](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/qstring.html#QString-7) that could take pointer as argument. But there are two QString constructors in [Qt 4.7](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qstring.html) that can take pointer as argument. I think this raised the compiler error.

You can force it to behave like Qt 4.6 as follows:

```
name((const char*) 0)
```

Comment: default initialization will do the same thing, so he can just omit the `: name( 0 )`

Answer (score 0):

whereever you are creating a QString with an int - you need to tell Qt what you mean by an int

If it's an actual literal number you are converting to a string use the QString("%u").arg() function